# Problemas con Models y Schemas de MongoDB usando mongoose en NodeJs postman

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, postman

estoy realizando el backend y utilizando postaman para ver si guardo bien los datos en la base de datos, el problema es que quiero crear un json con varios parámetros que son String y otro objetos que contengas mas info, pero cuando almaceno los datos no consigo que queden como me gustaría, os presento el código para ver si me podéis ayudar.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

// El esquema
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String },
    pass: { type: String },
    puesto: { type: String },
    usuario: [{
      img: { type: String },
      lastname: { type: String },
      nacimiento: { type: Date },
      email: { type: String },
      name: { type: String }
    }],
    {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
// El modelo
const User = model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Ese era el modelo, ahora os presento el controlador de creación, la idea es que un admin cree el usuario sin meter toda la info y dicho user rellene los parámetros faltantes. Esta es la parte del admin:

```js
    saveDataForm: async (req, res) => {

        let nombre = req.body.username;
        let contrasena = req.body.password;
        let puesto = req.body.puesto;
        
        const user = Usuario.create({
                    username: nombre,
                    pass: contrasena,
                    puesto: puesto,

                });
                
     res.json({
                    message: true
                })
                
    }
```

Y para terminar, os enseño la parte que envía el usuario para terminar de conseguir la información para la base de datos:

```js
regUser: async (req, res) => {
        let userN = req.body.username; 
        let img = req.body.img;
        let name = req.body.name;
        let lastName = req.body.lastname;
        let email = req.body.email;
        let nacimiento = req.body.birth;

        const usuarioFind = {  username : userN };
        const searchUser = await Usuario.findOneAndUpdate( usuarioFind,{
           $push: {
            usuario: [{
                img: img,
                name: name,
                lastname: lastName,
                nacimiento: nacimiento,
                email: email
            }]
           }
        });

       res.json({
        message: true,
        searchUser
       })
    },
```

Bien la cosa es que almaceno bien los datos en la base de datos y realizó correctamente las búsquedas o eso parece, el problema es que me gustaría que se almacenara de esta manera

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63d28c90dde8d80b48c08e83"
  },
  "pass": "Federico123",
  "usuario": {
    "img": "url de la imagen",
    "lastname": "montalvo",
    "nacimiento": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "538358400000"
      }
    },
    "puesto": "Diseñador",
    "email": "javier@gmail.com",
    "name": "Javier"
  }
  }
```

en vez de así:

```js
"usuario": [
    {
      "img": "imagen",
      "lastname": "Casa Nova",
      "nacimiento": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "415494000000"
        }
      },
      "email": "casaNova@gmail.com",
      "name": "Eduardo",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63d3b8825ccdbcdd96f6d017"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Pero... es que en tu `userSchema`, usuario es un array... porque esperas que se grabe como un objeto? Si quieres que usuario sea un único objeto con las propiedades que mencionas, entonces quita el array del schema y cambia el `findOneAndUpdate` para que no haga `$push` al array sino que solo cambie la propiedad

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el operador `$addToSet` este agrega un objeto a la matriz y en caso de existir no hace nada:

```
const model = {
    img: img,
    name: name,
    lastname: lastName,
    nacimiento: nacimiento,
    email: email
};

const searchUser = await Usuario.updateOne(
    { _id: usuarioFind },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            usuario: [model]
        }
    }
);
```

De igual manera te aconsejo que en las respuestas lo manejes con la función `status` del `res` de esta manera en el body puedes enviar la información:

```
res.status(200).json({
    message: true,
    searchUser
});
```